# Working on interpreters text -- how do I manage code dependencies between exercises?

Tags: version-control, scheme

I'm working through a text on Scheme interpreters (EOPL1).  Most of the problems involve implementing a feature or modifying an existing implementation.  Some of the problems are dependent on previous ones.

I want to have working interpreters and test cases for each problem without copy-pasting the whole interpreter for each exercise.  Previously I tried just loading the previous code and then redefining various functions, but this is bad: it's ugly and hard to tell which code is currently loaded, it doesn't eliminate code duplication when I make small changes to a module, and it creates bugs (e.g., when `struct` definitions get redefined).  It's getting a bit unmanageable.

I don't want to make a monolithic file with lots of #ifdefs or equivalent.  Is this a sane use case for (lots and lots of) VCS branches?  If not, what should I do?

(Apologies if the tags for this question aren't appropriate.)

Comment: Not being a version control expert, I won't post a full answer, but it does seem like a perfect use case for a DVCS with lightweight branching. Git handles this stuff well, but it has a somewhat steep learning curve (which I am still on -- hence the comment rather than a full answer). I'm sure a Git expert can give a fuller answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't require any branches.  Simple version control is all you need.  For this type of work I'd recommend [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).  To me, that's the simplest and easiest to use version control out of the box.  Alternatives would be [git](http://git-scm.com/), [perforce](http://perforce.com/), or [subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/).  (Obviously, there are many others)

Just start adding things as you need them.  It will keep track of revisions for you.  You certainly could create branches if you need to, or you could simply tag things for different exercises.  There are lots of possible workflows that should work. Although just about anything will be better than what you are doing now.

Comment: Many of the extensions are mutually exclusive, so it's not possible just to build on the interpreter code.  Since I don't want to copy/paste the base interpreter many times, I wondered about branches.  How do you solve this without branches?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly, but if branches make sense to you, it's likely the right approach.  I've never written any scheme, so I'm not familiar with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, I really like [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) for keeping the code, and [github](https://github.com/) is another alternative, if you want to have your code available anywhere.